# Dependencymanagement import with dependencies

Tags: maven

I have the following 3 maven modules:

- `service`
- `client`
- `interface`

In addition, I also have the following two maven artifacts:

- `general-parent`
- `general-parent-dependency`

The 3 modules all inherit from `general-parent`, like so:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>general-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</parent>`
```

`general-parent-dependencies` contains both `<dependencies/>` and `<dependencyManagement/>` sections.

The 3 modules should all import `<dependencyManagement/>`, but only the `service` module should import `<dependencies/>`.

I thought of adding the the `general-parent-dependencies` to the `general-parent` like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>general-parent-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>general-parent-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>     
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>`
</dependencyManagement>
```

So that from `client` I can refer to `general-parent-dependencies` without version and all the modules will have the `<dependencyManagement/>` inherited from `general-parent`.

But it does not work. Is it not possible to list the same artifact as a dependency in the `<dependencyManagement/>` twice like I did - using the `import` scope the first time and the default scope (`compile`) the second time?

Comment: Best practices to have only the dependencyManagement in the parent but no `dependencies` in the parent. Each child defines it's dependencies..makes it clear etc...

Answer (score 2):

If you declare dependencies in the parent pom, *all* child modules will inherit these dependencies.

If you want the dependencies only in *some* of the child modules, you either need to transfer them to the child modules or you need to wrap them into a profile and activate this profile only in certain child modules.